# Use shared system libraries in Conda

Tags: shared-libraries, conda, cluster-computing

I am using Conda on a shared compute cluster where numerical and io libraries have been tune for the system.
How can I tell Conda to use these and only worry about the libraries and packages which are not already *there* on `path`?

For example:

There is a `openmpi` library installed and the package which I would like to install and mange with `Conda` has it also as a dependency.
How can I tell Conda to *just* worry about what is *not* there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick is to use a *shell package* - an empty package whose only purpose is to satisfy constraints for the solver. This is something that Conda Forge does with `mpich`, as mentioned in [this section of the documentation](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-external-message-passing-interface-mpi-libraries). Namely, for every version, they include an `external` build variant, that one could install like

```bash
conda install mpich=3.4.2=external_*
```

signaling that it will be supplied by the host. One can consult [the recipe's `meta.yaml`](https://github.com/conda-forge/mpich-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml) for a concrete example.

I don't think this is great (seems like a lot of work), but I also don't know of a better alternative.